# How to subtract and add days and months in a mongodb 4.4 aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb4.0

I am trying to add and subtract few days and months from current date depending on the frequency and sequence of the notifications to be sent on these days. i.e

[image]

Here if the frequency is days and sequence is before means I have to notify it before given interval days from today. I am trying to construct the date based on `$dateFromParts` and adding or subtracting the interval days, however problem is when the month changes due to the addition or subtraction it fails to give correct date. Here is the pipeline stage I am using to calculate the expiry date -

```
expirydate : {
        $cond : [
            {
                $eq : [
                    '$sequence',
                    'Before'
                ]
            },
            {
                $cond : [
                    {
                        $eq : [
                            '$recurrence',
                            'days'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $dateFromParts : {
                            year : {
                                $year : '$today'
                            },
                            month : {
                                $month : '$today'
                            },
                            day : {
                                $subtract : [
                                    '$interval',
                                    {
                                        $dayOfMonth : "$today"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            hour : {
                                $hour : "$today"
                            },
                            minute : {
                                $minute : "$today"
                            },
                            second : {
                                $second : "$today"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $dateFromParts : {
                            year : {
                                $year : '$today'
                            },
                            month : {
                                $subtract : [
                                    '$interval',
                                    {
                                        $month : '$today'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            day : {
                                $dayOfMonth : "$today"
                            },
                            hour : {
                                $hour : "$today"
                            },
                            minute : {
                                $minute : "$today"
                            },
                            second : {
                                $second : "$today"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                $cond : [
                    {
                        $eq : [
                            '$recurrence',
                            'days'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        $dateFromParts : {
                            year : {
                                $year : '$today'
                            },
                            month : {
                                $month : '$today'
                            },
                            day : {
                                $add : [
                                    '$interval',
                                    {
                                        $dayOfMonth : "$today"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            hour : {
                                $hour : "$today"
                            },
                            minute : {
                                $minute : "$today"
                            },
                            second : {
                                $second : "$today"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $dateFromParts : {
                            year : {
                                $year : '$today'
                            },
                            month : {
                                $add : [
                                    '$interval',
                                    {
                                        $month : '$today'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            day : {
                                $dayOfMonth : "$today"
                            },
                            hour : {
                                $hour : "$today"
                            },
                            minute : {
                                $minute : "$today"
                            },
                            second : {
                                $second : "$today"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

and with that I am getting below result, which isn't correct. I have mongodb 4.4 Database hence I can't use `$dateAdd` or `$dateSubtract`. Any suggestions or pointers what should be improved or corrected.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: For days you can simply use `{$add: ["$today, {$multiply: ["$interval", 1000*60*60*24]}]}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for the response, yeah days could work that way but I am still not sure about how to handle the months. :(

Comment: You can add Months and Days directly, see [Value is Greater than the Range](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/#value-is-greater-than-the-range). `{ $dateFromParts: { 'year' : 2017, 'month' : 14, 'day': 1, 'hour' : 12  } }` gives `2018-02-01 12:00:00`

Comment: yeah so far seems like that is the only way. I am worried about backward compatibility of mongo 5 to 4.4, need some analysis else I would upgrade.

Comment: You have to consider cases like "add 1 Month to 2022-01-31". You need to add exceptions for "last day of the Months". Anyway, if you implement it manually in MongoDB 4.4 then it will also work in 5.0